# How do I prove that these vectors form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I know that by definition of basis, the vectors v1 and v2 should span the entire subspace. Therefore, if the first constant is not equal to the second constant, and if both of the constants give a linear transformation, then they must be linearly independent and therefore must form a basis. Is that the correct proof, or am I missing this? Also I don't know what the matrix of the linear transformation is.

Comment: "...then they must be linearly independent".  I don't see where you justify this claim.  And what is "they"?  You want to prove the vectors $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent, but you only refer to constants and linear transformations in the argument leading up to that.  There's no place where you have considered anything about the vectors.

Comment: A standard exercize shows that two eigenvectors relative to two distinct eigenvalues must be linearly independent. If you are using this fact, then everything becomes obvious; but if you don't, then you are using some unjustified argument.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $c_1 \vec v_1 + c_2 \vec v_2 = 0.$  Multiply both sides by $A$ to get $c_1 \lambda_1 \vec v_1 + c_2 \lambda_2 \vec v_2 = 0.$  Multiply the first equation by $\lambda_1,$ and subtract it from the the second to get $(\lambda_2 - \lambda_1) c_2 \vec v_2 = 0.$  Because the $\lambda$s are distinct and $\vec v_2$ is not zero, we must have $c_2 = 0.$  By a similar argument, $c_1 = 0.$  Hence $\vec v_1, \vec v_2$ are linearly independent. Now, there are two of them, and the space $\Bbb R^2$ has exactly two dimensions, so $\vec v_1, \vec v_2$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^2.$

The $i$th column of the matrix of $T_A$ is $[T_A \vec v_i]_{\mathcal B}$ where $[ \cdot ]_{\mathcal B}$ denotes the coordinate matrix relative to $\mathcal B.$  We compute
$$\begin{align}
[T_A \vec v_1]_{\mathcal B} & = [A \vec v_1]_{\mathcal B} = [\lambda_1 \vec v_1]_{\mathcal B} = [\lambda_1 \vec v_1 + 0 \cdot \vec v_2]_{\mathcal B} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}\\\\
[T_A \vec v_2]_{\mathcal B} & = [A \vec v_2]_{\mathcal B} = [\lambda_2 \vec v_2]_{\mathcal B} = [0 \cdot \vec v_1 + \lambda_2 \vec v_2]_{\mathcal B} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ \lambda_2\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}$$
Thus, the matrix of $T_A$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{bmatrix}.$$